# How to insert VNC Server license key (automatically) after a PC reimage with MDT

Tags: scheduled-tasks, license, task-scheduler, vncserver, mdt

I have a base build PC which has the VNC Server license key inserted and working correctly. I've then taken an image of it via WINPE disk and the DISM command line (.WIM file)

Wim file is then imported into MDT and then re-deployed out to multiple devices, hassle free. Unfortunately the Serial Key for VNC Server doesn't capture/deploy out to the other devices. Yet all other software license keys are transferred correctly and working fine.

Is there a Task Sequence in MDT I need to adjust? 
Or a Task Schedule I can change locally on the build? 
Or even a reg file I need to update?
Or a .bat file?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Typically, when using MDT you will use a basically vanilla image and then create application selections in MDT and deploy software application after the image is deployed. This gives you the flexibility to pick and choose what you want installed on any particular system and you can set defaults to make a few less clicks. With that said, the problem you are experiencing is not uncommon and that is why it is not good to wrap up software in an image. Look in to how to deploy the VNC server silently with your activation key. Then create a script / MDT task to do that after the image is deployed.

Comment: There are lots of different VNC versions, it would help to clarify the exact version you are using if you want anyone to recommend how to activate / deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

This was for VCN Server.

I have worked it out - I need to run a Powershell command via the Task Scheduler -

& '.\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncconfig.exe' -noconsole -license XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

This has resolved my issue. Still hasn't really helped as to why the capture didn't take the serial key across to the new deployment, but it's working which is the ultimate outcome.

Thanks!